# how to trigger a javascript popup message from try .. catch block in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, try-catch

I am trying to display error messages caught in Try Catch Block using Javascript. Please see my code. Same javascript function works fine if I call it normally but it doesn't work calling from a catch block. Is it not possible or what did I do wrong? Is there any alternatives?

Thanks so much.

```
Try
          Messagebox("Hello World") **'This works**
          Throw New Exception("OH NO")
Catch ex As Exception
            Messagebox(ex.Message) **'This doesn't work**
End Try

Protected Sub Messagebox(ex as string)

           'show ex as javascript error message
           Dim sb as stringbuilder = "javascript code here"
           Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "uniqueName", sb.ToString())

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? there is no reason this code shouldn't work by looking at what you have displayed here.

Comment: I made a new one page project and tested it everything .. now it works .. the problem was ex.Message itselt have some messy data that javascript function doesn't like. ex.Message was just an example actually we have custom xml error message function so. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? if so, could you paste it ?

Comment: @BrOSs My problem was just having single qoutes in the error  message .. i just solved it by *message = message.Trim.Replace("'", " ")*